# Ziggeo SDK Video Player - get seek time

Tags: api, video, sdk, ziggeo-sdk

In any of Ziggeo's SDKs, 
**Can you find out what second of the video the player is at?**

I want to know when a viewer gets 30 seconds into the video (for example).

There seem to be methods (events) like play, pause, seek; but it's not obvious if any of them can return a value of where in the video the user is.

I could infer where they are by watching play and pause events, but a seek would go to an unpredictable part of the video

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said, there are several events that would be of use for such implementation and I will presume that you are going to be using v2 (as that is the recommended way to go with).

The events are:

1. playing
2. paused
3. ended
4. seek

`playing` event will be activated in 3 cases:

1. the video playback is started
2. the play action is activated after the video was paused
3. the seek option was used to reach specific point in video, `seek` event fired and then playing will fire as well (since video is now playing again).

`paused` event will be activated in 2 cases:

1. when someone clicks on pause button
2. at the very end, pause event fires, followed by `ended` event.

`ended` and `seek` events fire only when the specific case presents itself (end of video or seek was used respectively).

`seek` event however has a parameter that is passed into the function - the `position` allowing us to quickly get the exact time the seek operation happened on.

- Knowing this, we know what to expect and when.

The way to get the data (any video data) would be to use `embedding.get();`. Using it as is, will return an entire object of useful details, however for position you would just type 'position'.

This is the code of events that would work:

```js
player.on('playing', function(){
  console.log('This is "playing" event from ' + player.get('position') + ' of ' + player.get('totalduration') );
});
player.on('paused', function(){
  console.log('This is "paused" event at ' + player.get('position') + ' of ' + player.get('totalduration') );
});
player.on('ended', function(){
  console.log('This is "ended" event at ' + player.get('position') + ' of ' + player.get('totalduration') );
});
player.on('seek', function(position){
  console.log('This is "seek" event at ' + player.get('position') + ' of ' + player.get('totalduration') );
  console.log('quicker way and more reliable:' + position);
});
```

- You can see there grabbing the 'position' and the 'totalduration', this is just for the example.
- It is good to point out that the seek event gets the right data within the position parameter, so use that instead of the .get() method as it could tell you a slightly "older" value.

Following is the complete code snippet, however you need to add your own application token and video token.
To do that, just replace the "APP_TOKEN" with your application token and "VIDEO_TOKEN" with video token or key.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- We are declaring our resource calls at this location -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://assets-cdn.ziggeo.com/v2-stable/ziggeo.css" />
    <script src="https://assets-cdn.ziggeo.com/v2-stable/ziggeo.js"></script>
    <script>
      var ziggeoapp = new ZiggeoApi.V2.Application({
        token:"APP_TOKEN",
        webrtc_streaming: true
      });
      ZiggeoApi.V2.Locale.setLocale("en");
      // the above can be quickly retrieved from https://ziggeo.com/docs/sdks/javascript/browser-integration/header

      //utilizing application event. This makes sure that the code is checked for after DOMReady and Ziggeo system is initialized.
      //application events: https://ziggeo.com/docs/sdks/javascript/browser-interaction/application-events
      ziggeoapp.on('ready', function() {
        var player = new ZiggeoApi.V2.Player({
          element: document.getElementById('player_placeholder'),
          attrs: {
            countdown: 3,
            width: 640,
            height: 480,
            theme: 'modern',
            themecolor: 'red',
            video: 'VIDEO_TOKEN'
          }
        });

        player.activate();

        //if we want to listed to all embeddings on the page, regardless of knowing which it is, we could use the application wide embedding events approach (global events system): https://ziggeo.com/docs/sdks/javascript/browser-interaction/application-embedding-events
        //however the private events seem much better for reacting to them
        //https://ziggeo.com/docs/sdks/javascript/browser-interaction/events
        player.on('playing', function(){
          console.log('This is "playing" event from ' + player.get('position') + ' of ' + player.get('totalduration') );
        });
        player.on('paused', function(){
          console.log('This is "paused" event at ' + player.get('position') + ' of ' + player.get('totalduration') );
        });
        player.on('ended', function(){
          console.log('This is "ended" event at ' + player.get('position') + ' of ' + player.get('totalduration') );
        });
        player.on('seek', function(position){
          console.log('This is "seek" event at ' + player.get('position') + ' of ' + player.get('totalduration') );
          console.log('quicker way and more reliable:' + position);
        });
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="player_placeholder"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I have added comments with links within the code, which should hopefully give additional information.